# Populates HashMap with the incorrect values.

Tags: java, reflection, hashmap

I am using the Reflection API to calculate the afferent and efferent couplings of a class and in turn calculate the Stability metric of each class. Then adding the results to a HashMap. The program seems to run correctly when I run the debugger, and it seems to pass the correct values to the HashMap.

When I check the return statement of the method (**which is the map**) the Key is correct (**Key is a class)**, the value (**Value is the measure object**) is incorrect. The value is always the result for one of the interfaces.

When the Map returns after calculation it has **the correct key**, but the **value associated with each key is incorrect**. The value is the same for each Key

```
 public ClassMap getEfferent(ClassList list){
    map = new ClassMap();
    measure = new Measurement();

    //cycle through the list
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

        //Get the class needed for efferent inspection
        Class cla = list.getMyClass(i);

        //get the interfaces from the class
        Class[] interfaces = cla.getInterfaces();

        //if the class implements any interfaces increment efferent
        for(Class inter : interfaces){

            //if the interface is part of the list
            if(list.contains(inter)){
                efferentCoupling++;
            }

        }//end interfaces

        Constructor[] cons = cla.getConstructors();
        Class[] conParams;

        for(Constructor c: cons){

            conParams = c.getParameterTypes();

            for(Class par: conParams){

                //if the paramater name is on the list of classes ++
                if(list.contains(par.getName())){
                    efferentCoupling ++;
                }

            }

        }//end Constructor params

        Field[] fields = cla.getFields();

        for(Field fie: fields ){

            //if the field name is on the list of classes ++
            if(list.contains(fie.getName()))
                efferentCoupling ++;


        }//fields

        //get the methods for the class
        Method[] classMethods = cla.getMethods();
        Class[] params;

        //
        for(Method meth: classMethods){

            Class returnTypes = meth.getReturnType();

            if(list.contains(meth.getReturnType().getName())){
                efferentCoupling ++;
            }

        }

        //pass in the list and the class name to check for afferent coupling
        //return the afferent score as an interger
        afferentCoupling = getAfferent(list, cla.getName());

        Name = cla.getName();

        //pass the the class name into setClassName
        measure.setClassName(Name);

        //pass in the efferentCoupling for the class
        measure.setEfferentCoupling(efferentCoupling);
        //pass in the afferentCoupling for the class
        measure.setAfferentCoupling(afferentCoupling);

        //System.out.println(measure.getStability());
        cla = list.getMyClass(i);

        //put the class(key) measure (value)
        map.put(cla, measure);

    }//end for


    //resets efferent coupling
    efferentCoupling = 0;

    return map;
}//getAfferent


//method passes in the ClassList and the class name to be checked
public int getAfferent(ClassList list, String name){
    int afferent = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

        //Get the class needed for afferent inspection
        Class cla = list.getMyClass(i);

        Class[] interfaces = cla.getInterfaces();

        //if the class implements any interfaces increment efferent
        for(Class inter : interfaces){

            //if the interface name is same as inter.getName() then increment afferent
            if(inter.getName() == name){
                afferent ++;
            }

        }//end interfaces

        Constructor[] cons = cla.getConstructors();
        Class[] conParams;

        for(Constructor c: cons) {

            conParams = c.getParameterTypes();

            for (Class par : conParams) {

                //if constructor params == name then increment
                if (par.getName() == name) {
                    afferent++;
                }
            }
        }

        Field[] fields = cla.getFields();
        for(Field fie: fields ){

            if(fie.getName() == name)
                afferent++;
        }//fields

        Method[] classMethods = cla.getMethods();
        Class[] params;

        for(Method meth: classMethods){

            Class returnTypes = meth.getReturnType();

            if(meth.getReturnType().getName() == name){

                afferent ++;
            }

        }
    }

    return afferent;
}
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] and clarify your input and expected vs. actual output?

Comment: Can you show us a simple example of where you are using the HashMap and a reproducible tests where it is not giving the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put

```
measure = new Measurement();
```

inside your for loop.

Currently you are only creating one Measurement and modifying + adding it multiple times in your loop.
So all your keys will point to the same Measurement object (Probably having the data for the last iteration of your loop.)

Comment: Thanks, that was it.